# Indefinite integral of g(x) * g'(x)

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

I'm given the question
$\int g(x) * g'(x) dx $
The integral evaluates to
$1/2[g(x)]^2 + C$
but I have absolutely no idea how to arrive at that conclusion.

My first thought was that the $g(x)*g'(x)$ looked somewhat similar to the product rule, and that I could somehow use that with the fundamental theorem of calculus to arrive at the answer, but I had no luck. I see multiple questions like this in my calc textbook and I never really know how to approach them.

Comment: A simple substitution approach... $y=g(x),dy=g'(x)dx$, then you have $\int ydy$...

Comment: Just observe that $\frac12\bigl(g^2(x)\bigr)'=g(x)g'(x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simply a matter of [integration by parts](https://www.mathsisfun.com/calculus/integration-by-parts.html).

Our integral is as such:
$$
\displaystyle\int g(x) \cdot g'(x)
$$
We can rename this, and then use integration by parts, like so ($u(x)$ and $v(x)$ both represent $g(x)$):
$$
\begin{align}
& \displaystyle\int g(x) \cdot g'(x) \\
= & \displaystyle\int u(x) \cdot v'(x) \\
= & u(x)v(x) - \displaystyle\int u'(x) \cdot v(x)
\end{align}
$$
Now rearranging:
$$
\displaystyle\int g(x) \cdot g'(x) = u(x)v(x) - \displaystyle\int u'(x) \cdot v(x) \\
2\cdot\displaystyle\int g(x) \cdot g'(x) = u(x)v(x) \\
\displaystyle\int g(x) \cdot g'(x) = \frac{u(x)v(x)}{2}
$$
Substituting in for $u(x)$ and $v(x)$:
$$
\begin{align}
&\displaystyle\int g(x) \cdot g'(x) = \frac{g(x)g(x)}{2} \\
=& \boxed{\displaystyle\int g(x) \cdot g'(x) = \frac{g(x)^2}{2}}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Note that you can also do this with a $u$-substitution, but this is the first approach that came to my mind

Comment: Thank you! I haven't learned integration by parts yet; but your answer gave me a better understanding of how to actually approach the problem and apply u substitution.

Comment: I'm glad that I could help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the product rule: $\int uv'dx = uv - \int u'vdx$, so we let $u = g(x), v' = g'(x)$ then $u' = g'(x), v = g(x)$

Then $\int g(x)g'(x) dx = g(x)g(x) - \int g'(x)g(x) dx \rightarrow 2 \int g(x)g'(x) dx = g(x)g(x) + C \rightarrow \int g(x)g'(x) dx = \frac{(g(x))^2}{2} + C_1$